# For Loop is returning information that it should not be when i put a break statement in

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to retrieve information from a SQL database which has types A,B and C, example being

```
COL1       COL2    
A          X
A          X
A          X
A          X
A          X
B          X
B          X
B          X
C          X
C          X
C          X
```

I have this code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string line = "";
        string d = ",";
        foreach (DataColumn c in T.Columns)
        {
            line = line + c.ColumnName + d;
        }
        sb.AppendLine(line);
        foreach (DataRow r in T.Rows)
        {
            line = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < T.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow R = T.Rows[i];
                if (R[0].ToString() != "A" )
                {
                    break;
                }
                line = line + r[i].ToString() + d;
            }
            sb.AppendLine(line);
        }

        File.WriteAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
```

When i run this and try get my output (a .csv file) it returns all rows and A,B and C values when i just want it to return the A values and stop.

Any advice?

Comment: put it line = line + r[i].ToString() + d; inside if (R[0].ToString() == "A") statement and remove break from it

Comment: If `i` is the index for the columns then what exactly is the point of `DataRow R = T.Rows[i]`?  What if there was one row and 5 columns?  That would throw an exception.

Comment: my apologies juharr, i will update the code for you so you can see the full class

Comment: Seeing more of the code will not clarify why you use a column index on the rows.

Comment: rashfmnb, when i tried that i would return Date for some reason

Comment: juharr, it is code i am playing around with, it returns the information i need for the time being, i will look to clean the code up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the first column to decide whether to output the row.

```
foreach (DataRow r in T.Rows)
{
    if(r[0]=="A")
    {
        line = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < T.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            line = line + r[i].ToString() + d;
        }
        sb.AppendLine(line);
    }
}
File.WriteAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
```

If your rows are ordered and you know you can stop after the first row that does not start with an A:

```
foreach (DataRow r in T.Rows)
{
    if(r[0]!="A") break;

    line = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < T.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        line = line + r[i].ToString() + d;
    }
    sb.AppendLine(line);
}
File.WriteAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Hi Steven

I had to change r[0] to r[0].ToString() for it to work but it has worked like a charm

Thank you very much